# Is there a built-in element for a bullet slider in android?

Tags: android-layout, android-view, android

Is there a ready-made view element in Android for (I don't know if this is the right name but) bullet sliders?

I mean this:

[image: Bullet slider]

Ideally a class that handles the activation of the bullet at the given the position would be perfect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for a [ViewPageIndicator](http://viewpagerindicator.com/). Check out the [sample app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.viewpagerindicator.sample).

[image]